# How to enable CORS properly in Spring Restfull WebService?

Tags: json, web-services, spring-mvc, cors

what i trying to achieve is consume my spring restful web service in another domain, but when i excute the json url that generated JSON value, my javascript console generate this error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/updatepool/1. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/updatepool/1. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Here is my JSON value that generated by these link http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/updatepool/1

> {"userid":1,"firstName":"brand","lastName":"bennet","email":"benjie@gmail.com"}

Here is my SpringController.java :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/updatepool/")
public class SpringServiceController {

    UserService userService = new UserService();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        User user=userService.getUserById(id);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Then i create SimpleCORSFilter based spring.io tutorial, so here is my SimpleCORSFilter.java class

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFIlter implements Filter{

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Here is how i consume the JSON value, first of all i create index.html file which is looked like
index.html

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Angular Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <p>User ID : {{greeting.userid}}</p>
        <p>firstName : {{greeting.firstName}}</p>
        <p>lastName : {{greeting.lastName}}</p>
        <p>email : {{greeting.email}}</p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my app.js

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceJsonSample/service/updatepool/1').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
}
```

i already create the CORS filter class why it still give me CORS blocked error? which i missed? i don't think that class is working properly, how do i have to trace the error?

Comment: Your custom filter 'SimpleCORSFIlter' needs to be registered in your web.xml file.

Comment: @BillBilal how to register it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like @Bill Bilal said, i have to register it to my web.xml, so here is how i register it in my web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.myapp.springservice.utility.SimpleCORSFIlter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I have not seen your question, I'm glad you found it. Don't forget to select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar CORS issue some time ago with a similar REST server. The headers were set in the REST server's base class, but it didn't seem to work. The only way I was able to fix it was by adding the following lines to my .htaccess file.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-type"
</ifModule> 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Comment: i don't use .htaccess file. Do you use java spring mvc technology? i never hear that file, but i do have many xml file

Comment: I suppose you have your REST WebService somewhere on a server in order to access it through the web. Usually there is an .htaccess file in the public_html directory of a server. If not, you can create one.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem by using this filter. It works fine with Spring Restful

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {      
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else { 
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }        
    }
}
```

I found this on the post [angularjs spring cross-origin request blocked](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/cross-origin-request-blocked-spring-mvc-restful-angularjs.html)

Hope this help.