# How to customize the 403 Forbidden/Access Denied Page using Spring Security

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm a junior web developper and I need to customize the 403 error page using react js, I've found other projects implementing the AccessDeniedHandler interface but I don't know how to use it in my Security Configuration class.

This is my CustomAccessDeniedHandler class :

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAccessDeniedHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                       HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                       AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("accessDenied");
        Authentication auth
                = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (auth != null) {
            logger.info("User '" + auth.getName()
                    + "' attempted to access the protected URL: "
                    + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
        }

        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest.getContextPath() + "/accessDenied");
    }
}
```

This is the Security Configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AppUserService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint() {})
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(getProvider())
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(new AuthentificationLoginSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new AuthentificationLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/categories").hasAuthority("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/createCategory").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    private class AuthentificationLoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }

    private class AuthentificationLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {
        @Override
        public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider getProvider() {
        AppAuthProvider provider = new AppAuthProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to create `@Bean`

```
@Bean
public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
    return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
}
```

which you already have and then add that handler in http security object like this:

```
http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint() {}) //remove this line or use Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint instead
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(getProvider())
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(new AuthentificationLoginSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new AuthentificationLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/categories").hasAuthority("USER")
            .antMatchers("/api/createCategory").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
```

As you can see you are missing:

```
.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
```

Additional, remove

```
@Autowired
private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
```

because you shouldn't autowire bean, you should create it with custom implementation.

EDIT:
If you have `@RestControllerAdvice` or `@ControllerAdvice` as global exception handler you should do following:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> exception(Exception exception) throws Exception {
        if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            throw exception;
        } 
...
```

then it should work because when you throw exception it will go to custom handler which we do what you wrote. Also you can debug `ExceptionTranslationFilter` method `handleSpringSecurityException`

> code from [ExceptionTranslationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java)

```
private void handleSpringSecurityException(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, RuntimeException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            logger.debug(
                    "Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point",
                    exception);

            sendStartAuthentication(request, response, chain,
                    (AuthenticationException) exception);
        }
        else if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) || authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication)) {
                logger.debug(
                        "Access is denied (user is " + (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) ? "anonymous" : "not fully authenticated") + "); redirecting to authentication entry point",
                        exception);

                sendStartAuthentication(
                        request,
                        response,
                        chain,
                        new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                            messages.getMessage(
                                "ExceptionTranslationFilter.insufficientAuthentication",
                                "Full authentication is required to access this resource")));
            }
            else {
                logger.debug(
                        "Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler",
                        exception);

                accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response,
                        (AccessDeniedException) exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

where you can see that 
`accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response,(AccessDeniedException) exception);`, in you case`CustomAccessDeniedHandler`, get called.

I just tried it and it is working fine with (I have `@ControllerAdvice` as global exception handler)

EDIT2:
You have to remove this line

```
.authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint() {})
```

from `SecurityConfig`, or change it to use `Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint` instead. This is the problem in your case.

Comment: well, what you said is totally logic, but I tried exactly that and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, then you must have some '@ControllerAdvice' or '@RestControllerAdvice' in your code? I edited my answer

Comment: thank you for tha @Lemmy but where should I add those two methods ?

Comment: You have to remove this line

.authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint() {})

Comment: @MahdiEzzahir i missed that part

Comment: I tried but I found an other error :  'Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: you have to enable CORS like this '@Configuration'
'@EnableWebMvc'
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    '@Override'
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
See this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Comment: @MahdiEzzahir also you can check this one for CORS configuration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319396/cors-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-not-working

Comment: I got another error and I couldn't achieve my purpose. Anyway I will mark it because you helped me a lot and it seems that resolved the concerned problem. Thank you @Lemmy

Comment: @MahdiEzzahir if you have another problem feel free to post another question. If error is about CORS please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587570/how-to-enable-cors-properly-in-spring-restfull-webservice/32603261#32603261, there are CORSFilter example and how to use it